# GA event tracking on link only fires when href='#'

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

This is my GA Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

This code reports to GA Event tracking:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SiteQA2', 'click', 'Analytics click']);" class="button button-style4 button-big">Get Started</a></li>
```

But this code doesn't:

```
<li><a href="./page2.php?id=5" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SiteQA2', 'click', 'Analytics click']);" class="button button-style4 button-big">Get Started</a></li>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that the GA tracking isn't firing, but that the data isn't being recorded.

`_trackEvent` records data by requesting a tracking pixel from analytics servers. Because the link visits a new page right after the `_trackEvent` call, the tracking pixel request can get canceled, resulting in no data being recorded.

The most common pattern is to add a slight delay (150ms works) before following the link to the new page. Do a search for "_trackEvent delay"

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.

I created this function with a small delay:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 

try { 
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action]); 
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.location.href = link.href;
}, 100);
}
</script>
```

And I call the links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) your answer from ga team!

I've modified this to get a more easy way:

```
trackBeforeHref : function(element, category, event, label) {
        ga('send', 'event', category, event, label, {'hitCallback':
          function () {
            document.location = element.href;
          }
        });
    },
```

then you can use in this way:

```
<a onclick="trackBeforeHref(this, 'a category', 'a event', 'a label'); return false;"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the facts that

1. `_gaq` executes the tasks pushed sequentially.
2. functions can be pushed into `_gaq` : [link to google developers article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?csw=1#PushingFunctions)

so the solution to the problem is

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
  // stop opening the link using return false at end of this event callback function
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  // pushing the track event task first and the call to open the href link so that both these tasks happen sequencially.
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'click', 'some_link' ], function(){ 
    window.location = href;
  });
  return false;
});
```